# ¿Se pueden añadir direcciones de memoria (punteros) en un arreglo? c++

Tags: c++

Teniendo un puntero int

```
int* pointer= new int();
```

Puedo añadirlo a un arreglo tal cual:

```
arrPointer[0]=pointer;
```

Alguien que me explique si es posible. Que no he visto la forma de hacerlo por errores de tipos invalidos en el compilador. int != int*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Se pueden añadir direcciones de memoria (punteros) en un arreglo?

Si.

---

Cuando quieres un arreglo del tipo `T`, el formato es:

```
T arreglo[tamaño];
```

Por lo tanto, si quieres un arreglo de puntero a un tipo `T *`, el formato es:

```
T *arreglo[tamaño];
```

En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) el nombre de un arreglo es un puntero al primer elemento del mismo, por eso cuando creamos un arreglo al tipo `T` con memoria dinámica (usando el operador `new`), necesitamos un puntero:

```
//                  v <--- Queremos almacenar T
   T *arreglo = new T[tamaño];
// ^^^ <--- Puntero a T
```

Por lo tanto, para obtener un arreglo de punteros `T*` debemos hacer un doble puntero:

```
//                   vv <--- Queremos almacenar T*
   T **arreglo = new T*[tamaño];
// ^^^^ <--- Puntero a puntero a T
```

Esta sintaxis puede ser confusa, por eso en C++ moderno se desaconseja y en su lugar se fomenta usar la plantilla `std::array`:

```
std::array<int *, tamaño> arr;
//         ^^^^^ <--- Queremos almacenar int*
```

Pero si el tamaño no está prefijado se fomenta usar `std::vector`

```
std::vector<int *> vec;
//         ^^^^^ <--- Queremos almacenar int*
```

En todos los casos, podrás usar los corchetes (`[]`) para acceder a los elementos.

Answer (score 1):

Esta variable es un array de enteros... en este caso de longitud 1:

```
int* pointer= new int();
```

Al ser un array de enteros, únicamente podrá almacenar enteros.

Para almacenar punteros necesitas crear un array de punteros y, para ello, necesitas un puntero doble:

```
int** arrPointer = new int*();   // Array para almacenar un puntero
int** arrPointer = new int*[20]; // Array para almacenar 20 punteros
```

Con este tipo de array ya podrías hacer lo que propones:

```
arrPointer[0] = pointer;
```